# How to return datas with "App::setLocale('en')" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search part in my website. When i try to search certain value from my controller, it doesn't translate into the language i want on the page.

web.php

```
Route::post('/en/search-result',[SearchController::class,'searchData3']);
```

searchController.php

```
 public function searchData3(Request $req)
    {

            $pages = Page::all();         
            $ara = $req->input('ara');
            $data2 = Sold::where('baslik', 'like', "%{$ara}%" )
            ->orWhere('aciklama_kisa', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('aciklama', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('fiyat', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('kategori', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('ozellikler', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('oda', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->orWhere('tip', 'like', "%{$ara}%")
            ->get();

        return  view('tema.booking.en.sonuc2' ,  compact( 'data2' , 'pages'));
       
    }
```

my blade

```
<div class="search">
            <form id="search-form" method="post" action="/en/search-result">
                @csrf
                <input type="search" placeholder="{!! __('general.search') !!}" name="ara" id="site_search" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit-site-search" value="submit-site-search" name="submit-site-search" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

I can decide the language of the page like below, but I can't do it through the controller

```
 Route::get('/en', function () {
        App::setLocale('en');     // i want to be able to set my locale like this
        $slides = App\Slide::all();
        $themes = App\Theme::all();     
        $services = App\Service::all();
        $products = App\Product::all();
        $pages = TCG\Voyager\Models\Page::all();   
        $solds = App\Sold::all();      
        return view('tema.booking.en.index', compact('slides','services','themes','pages' ,'solds' , 'products'));
    });
```

Simply how can i return view from controller with "App::setLocale('en')

Comment: I can not see `App::setLocale('en')` in your controller

Comment: @Immeyti How can i add ?